# troubleshooting IIS server hang

Tags: performance, iis, iis-7, performance-testing

I have a pretty basic web api that uses entity framework to access a SQL server backend.  The api code just passes requests to some stored procs and returns data; nothing special.  I'm using .net 4.6 (constrained because I'm running on win 2008 standard).  I am NOT using async/await because I am constrained again by an old logging library that doesn't support that pattern.

I'm running a burst test where I create 30 threads that simultaneously call one api endpoint.  Each thread will wait one second between calls.  This creates a load of about 20 requests / second.

When I run the test, the performance is fine.  Calls return in < 50ms.  Then, about two minutes in (always at about the same time), asp.net will start queuing requests (according to perf mon), and then all of a sudden IIS will just hang and I'll get timeouts.  The CPU will spike to 99 percent which is odd because my code is all asynchronous waiting for DB calls.  The performance does not steadily degrade like in most cases.  It's fine, and fast, until all of a sudden it's not.

I don't get any errors thrown from my code.  Nothing useful in the event log.  I have all the default IIS settings except I changed my http.sys queue limit from 1000 to 5000 after reading that recommendation somewhere else, but it didn't help.

Any suggestions on what I can try or look at or do?  I'm kinda stumped here.

EDIT:  Incorrectly said I am using async/await.  I am not.

Here is the code, minus variable assignment and other irrelevant code.  The api call enters the top method, then the second, then the third

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("productvariantassociationids")]
    public LocatorServiceOutputModel GetProductVariantAssociationIds([FromUri]ProductVariantInput input)
    {
        var output =  ProductService.GetProductVariantAssociationIds(input);

        if ((output == null) || (output.Data == null) || (((List<int>)output.Data).Count == 0))
            throw new HttpResponseException(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        return output;
    }

public LocatorServiceOutputModel GetProductVariantAssociations(ProductVariantInput input)
    {   
        var output = new LocatorServiceOutputModel();
        var cachedData = CacheService.Get<List<ProductVariantAssociation>>(input.ToString());

        if (cachedData != null)
        {
            output.Data = cachedData;
            output.FromCache = true;                
        }
        else
        {
            var associations = ProductRepository.GetProductVariantAssociations(input.ProductLineTypeID, input.ProductVersionTypeID, input.FormCodeTypeID, input.PremiumStructureTypeID,
                                                                            input.DefinitionOfDisabilityTypeID, input.StateTypeID, input.ApplicationDate, input.InsurredAge);

            var mappedAssociations = Mapper.Map<List<ProductVariantAssociation>>(associations);
            CacheService.Set(input.ToString(), mappedAssociations);

            output.Data = mappedAssociations;
        }

        output.Success = true;
        return output;
    }

public List<DBRiderBenefit> GetRiderBenefits(int? productVariantAssociationID = null, StateTypeEnum? stateTypeID = null, int? insurredAge = null, DefinitionOfDisabilityTypeEnum? definitionOfDisabilityType = null,
                                                EliminationPeriodTypeEnum? eliminationPeriodTypeID = null, BenefitPeriodTypeEnum? benefitPeriodTypeID = null, MentalSubstanceLimitationEnum? mentalSubstanceLimitationID = null,
                                                OccupationClassTypeEnum? occupationClassTypeID = null, OccupationGroupTypeEnum? occupationGroupTypeID = null, string occupationTypeValueText = null,
                                                bool? isExercise = null, string callingSystemID = null, int? productVersionRevisionId = null)
    {
        using (ProductLibraryContext context = new ProductLibraryContext())
        {

            List<DBRiderBenefit> results = null;

            if (productVersionRevisionId != null)
            {
                results = context.Database.SqlQuery<DBRiderBenefit>("exec [USP_ProductLibrary_Get_RiderBenefit] @ProductVariantAssociationID, @StateTypeID, @IssuredAge, @DefinitionOfDisabilityID, @EliminationPeriodTypeID, @BenefitPeriodTypeID, @MentalSubstanceLimitationID, @OccupationClassTypeID, @OccupationGroupTypeID, @OccupationType_ValueText, @IsExercise, @CallingSystemId, @ProductVersionRevision"
                                                                                , paramProductVariantAssociationID, paramStateTypeID, paramInsuredAge, paramDefinitionOfDisabilityID, paramEliminationPeriodTypeID, paramBenefitPeriodTypeID
                                                                                , paramMentalSubstanceLimitationID, paramOccupationClassTypeID, paramOccupationGroupTypeID, paramOccupationTypeValueText, paramIsExercise, paramCallingSystemId, paramProductVersionRevision).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                results = context.Database.SqlQuery<DBRiderBenefit>("exec [USP_ProductLibrary_Get_RiderBenefit] @ProductVariantAssociationID, @StateTypeID, @IssuredAge, @DefinitionOfDisabilityID, @EliminationPeriodTypeID, @BenefitPeriodTypeID, @MentalSubstanceLimitationID, @OccupationClassTypeID, @OccupationGroupTypeID, @OccupationType_ValueText, @IsExercise, @CallingSystemId"
                                                                                , paramProductVariantAssociationID, paramStateTypeID, paramInsuredAge, paramDefinitionOfDisabilityID, paramEliminationPeriodTypeID, paramBenefitPeriodTypeID
                                                                                , paramMentalSubstanceLimitationID, paramOccupationClassTypeID, paramOccupationGroupTypeID, paramOccupationTypeValueText, paramIsExercise, paramCallingSystemId).ToList();
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you paste the code section where you are using the async/await - minor mistakes in async can cause deadlocks.

Comment: Apologies - I am NOT using async/await.  I was thinking of something else.  I edited the post to mention why I am not using async/await.  But I am posting the code anyway.